# lightbox 2 border around thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey guys Iam trying 2 use light box at the moment and every thing is working fine. However what iam trying 2 figure out is how do i get a border like http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ the ones which they got in the examples to change colour. Any help on this would be great.

html:

```
<div class = "image1">
<a href="images/image1.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image1t.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: either `:hover` and CSS3 transitions or a color animation plugin for jQuery.

Comment: Update: they use CSS3 transitions indeed. Look at the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
.image1 a {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: block;
float: left;
line-height: 1em;
margin-right: 40px;
padding: 7px;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
.image1 a:hover {
background-color: #8AD459;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali Check this and let me know if it works for you as required.image1 a {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 grey;
display: block;
float: left;
line-height: 1em;
margin-right: 40px;
padding: 7px;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}

Answer (score 1):

Set a css3 transition property on your anchors, then on :hover property, the effects will "animate".

```
.image1 a {
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}


.image1 a:hover {
background-color: #8ad459;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```